# How to find answers with a keyword not in the question?

Tags: support, answers, search

Questions that encourage many answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow. For example: "Can you list some practical examples of the Decorator pattern?" would solicit many answers, not one.

Instead of asking such questions, I would like to be able to find answers that use the term "decorator" when the questioner did not use it.  Then, I could (hopefully) create a list for my own purposes.

Is there a way of finding answers which use a keyword that is not in the question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=decorator%20is%3aanswer (will also bring back answers to questions with that word in their title)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard. That's not helpful.

Comment: care to explain why please?

Comment: Sorry. Thought it was a joke.  I had missed the rest of your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was suggested that you use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer for this, so [here's a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/271027/find-answers-containing-decorator-to-questions-not-containing-decorator) that works for it.

You'll probably want a `TOP` on this. It works without it, but it takes *just about* forever, as long as you're willing to consider "7915 rows returned in 156211 ms" to be forever, and I am.

```
SELECT answers.Id AS [Post Link], answers.*
FROM Posts questions
    INNER JOIN Posts answers ON questions.Id = answers.ParentId
WHERE
    questions.PostTypeId = 1 AND
    answers.PostTypeId = 2 AND
    answers.Body LIKE '%decorator%' AND
    questions.Body NOT LIKE '%decorator%'
```

You could also, of course, use a parameter if you cared to make this reusable. But I try to avoid too much feature creep in these answers.

Comment: Thanks. Here's what I did: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/271027/find-answers-containing-decorator-to-questions-not-containing-decorator

Answer (score -1):

Use `is:answer` in your search query to search through answers, rather than all posts.

Comment: This does not exclude answers to questions containing "decorator."

Comment: @JosiahYoder so your only option is the Data Explorer.